# Index an array of custom range type in PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, database, postgresql, indexing, custom-type

I've created a custom range type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION smallint_subtype_diff(x smallint, y smallint) RETURNS float8 AS
'SELECT (x - y)::float8' LANGUAGE sql STRICT IMMUTABLE;

CREATE TYPE smallintrange AS RANGE (
    subtype = smallint,
    subtype_opclass = int2_ops,
    subtype_diff = smallint_subtype_diff    -- required by GiST
);
```

It works fine and I can index it with GiST.

However, I now wish to index an array of this type: smallintrange[]

Regardless of whether I try GiST or GIN, I get this:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_Vendors_OpenTimes ON public.Vendors USING gin (OpenTimes);
```

> ERROR:  data type smallintrange[] has no default operator class for
>   access method "gin" HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the
>   index or define a default operator class for the data type.

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same error message is thrown when you try to index any built-in range types, f.ex. `int4range`. This is because there is no [built-in GIN operator class](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/gin-builtin-opclasses.html) for array of ranges. (There is no operator class for [GiST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/gist-builtin-opclasses.html) or [SP-GiST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/spgist-builtin-opclasses.html) either).

You should try to re-structure your data, f.ex. into a one-to-many relationship, where each `vendors` row can have multiple entry in a (let's say) `vendor_ranges`, where you can use a simple range (not an array of them). In that context you could index your ranges.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sure it could be extended, but that's a whole other level.